# Unable to add initial monitor to Ceph in RHEL

Tags: ceph

I am trying to set up a Ceph cluster. I have 4 nodes - 1 admin-node, 1 monitor and 2 object storage devices. The installation guide I am using is given at the following location: http://ceph.com/docs/master/start/quick-ceph-deploy/.

When I am trying to add the initial monitor (step 5 in the guide), I am getting the following error:

```
[ceph@ip9-114-194-12 mycluster]$ ceph-deploy mon create-initial
[ceph_deploy.conf][DEBUG ] found configuration file at: /home/ceph/.cephdeploy.conf
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ] Invoked (1.5.26): /usr/bin/ceph-deploy mon create-initial
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ] ceph-deploy options:
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  username                      : None
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  subcommand                    : create-initial
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  verbose                       : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  overwrite_conf                : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  prog                          : ceph-deploy
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  quiet                         : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  cd_conf                       : <ceph_deploy.conf.cephdeploy.Conf instance at 0x1ecdcb0>
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  cluster                       : ceph
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  func                          : <function mon at 0x1e82410>
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  ceph_conf                     : None
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  default_release               : False
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ]  keyrings                      : None
[ceph_deploy.mon][DEBUG ] Deploying mon, cluster ceph hosts ip9-114-194-113
[ceph_deploy.mon][DEBUG ] detecting platform for host ip9-114-194-113 ...
[ip9-114-194-113][DEBUG ] connection detected need for sudo
[ip9-114-194-113][DEBUG ] connected to host: ip9-114-194-113
[ip9-114-194-113][DEBUG ] detect platform information from remote host
[ip9-114-194-113][DEBUG ] detect machine type
[ceph_deploy.mon][INFO  ] distro info: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 6.5 Santiago
[ip9-114-194-113][DEBUG ] determining if provided host has same hostname in remote
[ip9-114-194-113][DEBUG ] get remote short hostname
[ip9-114-194-113][DEBUG ] deploying mon to ip9-114-194-113
[ip9-114-194-113][DEBUG ] get remote short hostname
[ip9-114-194-113][DEBUG ] remote hostname: ip9-114-194-113
[ip9-114-194-113][DEBUG ] write cluster configuration to /etc/ceph/{cluster}.conf
[ip9-114-194-113][DEBUG ] create the mon path if it does not exist
[ip9-114-194-113][DEBUG ] checking for done path: /var/lib/ceph/mon/ceph-ip9-114-194-113/done
[ip9-114-194-113][DEBUG ] done path does not exist: /var/lib/ceph/mon/ceph-ip9-114-194-113/done
[ip9-114-194-113][INFO  ] creating keyring file: /var/lib/ceph/tmp/ceph-ip9-114-194-113.mon.keyring
[ip9-114-194-113][DEBUG ] create the monitor keyring file
[ip9-114-194-113][INFO  ] Running command: sudo ceph-mon --cluster ceph --mkfs -i ip9-114-194-113 --keyring /var/lib/ceph/tmp/ceph-ip9-114-194-113.mon.keyring
[ip9-114-194-113][ERROR ] Traceback (most recent call last):
[ip9-114-194-113][ERROR ]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ceph_deploy/lib/vendor/remoto/process.py", line 118, in run
[ip9-114-194-113][ERROR ]     reporting(conn, result, timeout)
[ip9-114-194-113][ERROR ]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ceph_deploy/lib/vendor/remoto/log.py", line 13, in reporting
[ip9-114-194-113][ERROR ]     received = result.receive(timeout)
[ip9-114-194-113][ERROR ]   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ceph_deploy/lib/vendor/remoto/lib/vendor/execnet/gateway_base.py", line 704, in receive
[ip9-114-194-113][ERROR ]     raise self._getremoteerror() or EOFError()
[ip9-114-194-113][ERROR ] RemoteError: Traceback (most recent call last):
[ip9-114-194-113][ERROR ]   File "<string>", line 1036, in executetask
[ip9-114-194-113][ERROR ]   File "<remote exec>", line 12, in _remote_run
[ip9-114-194-113][ERROR ]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 642, in __init__
[ip9-114-194-113][ERROR ]     errread, errwrite)
[ip9-114-194-113][ERROR ]   File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1234, in _execute_child
[ip9-114-194-113][ERROR ]     raise child_exception
[ip9-114-194-113][ERROR ] OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[ip9-114-194-113][ERROR ]
[ip9-114-194-113][ERROR ]
[ceph_deploy.mon][ERROR ] Failed to execute command: ceph-mon --cluster ceph --mkfs -i ip9-114-194-113 --keyring /var/lib/ceph/tmp/ceph-ip9-114-194-113.mon.keyring
[ceph_deploy][ERROR ] GenericError: Failed to create 1 monitors
```